# Laravel download file not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

i make api in which i send image link then user can download image from this link

**1st problem**

$path = (public_path("images") . $filename);

echo $path than path would be like this

**"C:\wamp\www\jobpost\public\imagesPerson.PNG"**  // why its not put \ after images

i do this but error occur

**$path = (public_path("images") ."\". $filename);**

**2nd problem**

after i test image download or not i manually place the link

return **Response::download("C:\wamp\www\jobpost\public\images\Person.PNG");**

error occur

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response::download()

i am already use this at the top of my controller

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response; // i comment this and use

**use Response** //error remove

**3rd problem**

when i use Response

return **Response::download("C:\wamp\www\jobpost\public\images\Person.PNG");**

error occur

> Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::header()

i searched alot this is my header

```
   $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: PNG',

        );
```

i replace this

```
       return Response::download("C:\wamp\www\jobpost\public\images\Person.PNG");
```

from this

```
      return( Response::download( "C:\wamp\www\jobpost\public\images\Person.PNG", 'filename.PNG', $headers) );
```

but still problem not solve

my cors.php

**Cors.php**

```
$headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'=> '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true'

    ];
    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        $response->header($key, $value);
    return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

use
`response()->download("C:\wamp\www\jobpost\public\images\Person.PNG");`